# Gradient of trace of squared matrix logarithm

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, positive-definite, chain-rule

I have a simple question that confuses me for a while:

> $$f(X) = \text{tr} \left( [ \log(X) ]^2 \right)$$
>
> where $X$ is an $m \times m$ symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix and $\log(X)$ is the matrix logarithm of matrix $X$. What is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$?

Using the chain rule, I have

$df = \text{tr}(2ZdZ)$,

where $Z=\log (X)$. I think we should have $dZ = X^{-1}dX$ as a scalor function, so we will have

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = 2\log(X)X^{-1}$,

but I haven't found any related reference.

Any comment or hint will be appreciated!

Comment: Let $f'(s)=\frac{df}{ds}\,$ be the ordinary derivative of the scalar function $f$. Then the general formula for the gradient of the **trace** of this function applied to a matrix argument $X$ is $${\frac{\partial{\,\,\rm Tr}(f(X))}{\partial X} = f'(X^T)}$$ So your formula is correct, depending on your preferred layout convention, which appears to be the opposite of my own. BTW, the formula holds for any square matrix, not just SPD matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Careful: most of the standard calculus formulas for differentiation require things to commute.  Matrices don't.  So $d(Z^2)$ is not $2 Z \; dZ$, it's $Z \; dZ + (dZ)\; Z$.  And I don't think there is a closed-form formula for $d(\log Z)$.

However, if $X$ is symmetric, we can assume wlog that it is diagonal.  Then you can easily compute
$f(X + dX)$ for $dX$ with a single matrix element.

Comment: Yes. $X$ is symmetric (hence $Z$). In this case, do we have $Z dZ = dZ Z$, and  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = 2\log(X)X^{-1}$?

Comment: No, we don't.  $dZ$ and $Z$ don't commute.

Comment: But using trace trick, this won't be a problem, right? So, I guess the answer is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi:X\in U\mapsto \log(X)$, where $U$ is the set of $n\times n$ complex matrices that have no eigenvalues in $\mathbb{R}^-=(-\infty,0]$ (we use the principal $\log$). Its derivative is

cf. Higham, functions of matrices

$D\phi_X:H\in M_n\mapsto \int_0^1(t(X-I)+I)^{-1}H(t(X-I)+I)^{-1}dt$.

$\textbf{Proposition 1}$. Let $f:X\in M_n\mapsto tr(\log(X))$.

Then its derivative is $Df_X(H)=tr(X^{-1}H)$ and its gradient is $\nabla(f)(X)=X^{-T}$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. $Df_X(H)=tr(D\phi_X(H))=\int_0^1tr((t(X-I)+I)^{-1}H(t(X-I)+I)^{-1})dt=$

$\int_0^1tr((t(X-I)+I)^{-2}H)dt=tr(\int_0^1(t(X-I)+I)^{-2}dtH)=tr(X^{-1}H)$.

$\textbf{Proposition 2}$. Let $g:X\in M_n\mapsto tr((\log(X))^2)$.

Then its derivative is $Dg_X(H)=2tr(\log(X)X^{-1}H)$ and its gradient is

$\nabla(g)(X)=2X^{-T}\log(X^T)$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. $Dg_X(h)=2tr(\log(X)D\phi_X(H))=$

$2\int_0^1tr(\log(X)(t(X-I)+I)^{-1}H(t(X-I)+I)^{-1})dt$.

The key is that $\log(X)$ and $(t(X-I)+I)^{-1}$ commute (both are polynomials in $X$); then (as above)

$Dg_X(H)=2tr(\log(X)\int_0^1(t(X-I)+I)^{-2}dtH)=2tr(\log(X)X^{-1}H)$.

$\textbf{Remark}$.The derivative of the function $tr(A\log(X))$ (where $A\in M_n$ is fixed), is much more complicated!!